# Destructuring assignment, but without a pattern

Tags: javascript

The following appears to be valid JavaScript:

```js
const {} = { foo: 'foo' }
```

Is there a specific use-case for an empty destructuring assignment pattern (is this the right word?) like this?

Comment: I don't think there is a use case. It's just accepted grammar. It doesn't really make sense to use. These things happen a lot.

Comment: It doesn't *do* anything, so any use case involving no actions I guess

Comment: Wild supposition: it's in the grammar to make life easy for code generators in some edge cases (without really hurting anything)

Comment: I suppose the *only* use case I can actually think of is when automatically generating code. Say, you are producing "all properties from this list should have variables" but for whatever reason that list is empty. You can produce this code using the generic logic for code generation and you don't need to care for an edge case. Still, I'd say this would the EXTREME minority of use cases. If it ever comes up. I doubt that was the intention here or there was even an intention. Seems like there would be *more work* involved to ban this construct than just accept it.

Comment: De-structuring an object into an empty object annulate the very purpose of the assignment. If you want, let say de-structure and ignore a function return value, then you can just call the function and that's all. That to me is just grammatically correct code with no purpose at all, classical in javascript world ;)

Comment: I'd say it's there for consistency. It's permitted to destructure an empty property list because, otherwise, they'd have to implement code to disallow this form. Although it doesn't serve any purpose it's still perfectly correct; no different really from an unused variable or some other redundancy like that. It might also make the process of refactoring easier.

Comment: You can check this reference doc to get more insight: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @Pointy Actually, it does *something*: check for the right hand side to evaluate to an object. If its `null` or `undefined`, it will throw.

Comment: @Bergi oh right, that's a good point.

Comment: The spec specifically _includes_ the empty LHS object. And it can't really be hard to code 'an empty LHS object literal is not valid' (I mean, look at the other assignment operator EarlyError rules). So I vote for 'it's a mystery' at this point. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's there for consistency. It's permissible to destructure an empty property list because, otherwise, they'd have to implement code to spcifically disallow it.

Although it may not appear serve any purpose it's still perfectly correct; no different really from an unused variable or some other redundancy like that. It might also make the process of refactoring easier: properties can be added/removed to a destructuring pattern without worrying that you have to remove the whole assignment if you hit zero at some point in the middle.

Also, as @Bergi said in their comment, it does at least assert that the right hand side is an object, not null or undefined.

Comment: But… au contraire! The spec specifically _includes_ it, in the definition of ObjectAssignmentPattern at https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-destructuring-assignment?

Comment: Explained [here](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1253347821991931904?s=20) and [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/97).